# is it a good way to change UIViewControllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface

I'm new at developing iPhone applications. Application i want to write now is very simple.

I want to have to "screens". For doing this i've created to `UIViewController` subclasses for both of them. The first one have a button - and when it's pressed i want to change the screen to the second. For doing this i want to send a message to shared `AppDelegate` object and to change the view in my window.

Maybe it's important:
The first screen is used for entering ip address of the server i want to connect to. So this screen will appear only once in the application

Am i on the right way ?

Comment: Are you using any navigation controller for your app ie: UINavigationController, UITabBarController)?

Comment: No. Not at this moment. I want to understand the basics first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go along with what the others have already added. You should take a look(if you haven't already) at Apple's '[View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)'.  It will provide some good insight into managing the views, and provide examples of the different methods for doing so(Pushing,Modal,etc).

**EDIT**

Since it sounds like you want to show one view at a time(no stack, no modal) then you should really look at a [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to help organize your View Controllers.  This will allow you to switch from one to the other easily.  [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/EditingNibFileObjects/EditingNibFileObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH12) is some detail on how to set one up, you will need to scroll down to the 'Tab Bar' section.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I've already read this. But i don't understand if i can just replace the current view controller with the other one. And if i can - how to do this?

Comment: Do you consider the ViewController that requires the entering of the IP addresses to be something of an 'application setting' section and the other to be the actual applicaion?

Comment: Maybe. But i still want to know is it possible just to replace one viewController with another ?

Comment: I think(hope) I understand what you are asking!  It is possible, see my edit above.

Answer (score 3):

The APIs you are looking for are both found in UIViewcontroller:

```
- [UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:];
```

and

```
- [UIViewController dismissModalViewController:animated:];
```

Comment: I'm not sure i want the modal view because the first screen should be shown only once.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend you start with the second view controller and present the first over the top as a modal.

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if ull push and pop the viewControllers to the navigation.
code example:

```
-(IBAction) CallNumberClicked  
 {  
    static DialNumberViewController *viewController=nil;  
    if(viewController==nil)  
        viewController=[[DialNumberViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DialNumberViewController" bundle:nil];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is with protocols and callbacks.  The current ViewController calls back to an original one and the original one releases the "current" one.